# C Unexpected Identifier - For Loop Increment

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

Not sure what I've done here (pretty new to C, have done some Python, Arduino and Java before).

```
int main(void){
    unsigned long int sum = 0;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(unsigned long int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        if(i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0)
            printf("cond%d\n", i);
            count++;
            sum += i; // $$here$$
    return 0;
```

When I compile the code, I get 'error undefined identifier: i' on line 10 (indicated with $$here$$

Comment: You need curly braces for the `for` loop and `if` statement. You're out of the loop's scope at that line.

Comment: Your indentation is confusing you. Why is the `sum += i;` indented more than the `return`? They're in the same control block, aren't they?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because Python, I guess ;-)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The indentation is correct and not confusing; it correctly reflects the intent to have the most indented lines be controlled by the `if` statement. The error is the missing braces that C requires to effect this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The indentation should not reflect the intent though. Fixing the indentation would make the problem obvious. The compiler doesn't care what the code's intent is, and proper indentation shows the flow of the code.

Comment: I'd also note that `%d` is not the correct format specifier for a long int.  You should use `%lu` instead.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: How do you propose an author indent code to match the nested code structure they were unaware of instead of matching the nested code structure they intended? A person cannot on information they do not possess.

Comment: @EricPostpischil For one thing, the author could use a tool that automatically indents C code properly. There's a good change they're already using a GUI that has this feature.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If they were using such a tool, the code would have been indented that way already. It is not likely the tool indented the code differently from what they typed, they ignored it, and then they either copied the code here and reindented it or typed it from scratch with their own indentation, still ignoring the indentation of the tool.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Unless they didn't push the button. And if they weren't using such a tool, using one would have pointed them right at the problem. The OP would tremendously benefit from learning how to properly indent their code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: And so again, they must act on information they do not have: There is a button to indent code to match the language’s control flow. Your original comment remains incorrect; it is not the indentation that confused the user. The indentation came from them; it was not something external that was informing them or confusing them. Their confusion arised from lack of knowledge of how the language structures control flow, using braces; it was not caused by indentation. The indentation reveals to us what the OP was thinking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There is a persistent tendency on Stack Overflow to insist that people ought to “do things right” while neglecting what knowledge people do and do not have as they are learning. Analyze problems using their mental model, not yours.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry just a bit confused. What do you think the proper indentation is, considering that I only want to increment the value of i when the condition in the if statement is true?

If this was in Python or a language which doesn't use curly braces, then the indentation would be correct, no? So if the logic is the same if I port it over to Python, then why the different indentation?

Comment: @M.Choy That's what you're missing, Indentation in C should be based on the structure of the code, not its intended behavior.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz could you please provide an example of what you think it should be?

Comment: @M.Choy I used a tool called "indent" and used its default C indentation style. It produced [this](https://pastebin.com/fLt5nS1Z) which makes it much easier to understand what the code is doing and why. Properly indenting code makes its flow much easier to understand and there are numerous tools that do this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not use indentation to structure program control (such as to indicate that more-indented statements are controlled by a less-indented statement above them). To group statements under the control of an `if` or other statement, you must use braces:

```
        if(i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0)
        {
            printf("cond%d\n", i);
            count++;
            sum += i;
        }
```

The compiler error occurs because, due to the lack of braces, the scope of the `for` statements ends after the `printf` statement. So no declaration for `i` is visible at the `sum += i;` line, and the compiler complains.

The compiler will ignore most indentation and white space. When authors use indentation in C source code, it is to aid humans, not the compiler.

(C grammar does not require any braces around the `if` statement to keep it within the `for` statement’s control, because the `if` statement and the following lines form a single statement, once braces are added as shown above. However, many people would add braces just around the `if` statement to illustrate explicitly that it forms the body of the `for` statement. I treat this contextually, judging what is clearer in each situation.)